# How to make X-Scroll in a gridView asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to add scroll bars in both x and y but I only can add y-scroll.
At the moment, my gridview is showing only partial data, it is missing  3-4 columns so I really need to use x-scroll. I've tried "overflow-x: scroll;" but it doesn't work.

My source code

```
<div style= "overflow-x:scroll; Overflow:scroll; max-height: 150px; width: 800px">
                                                    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewUpBus" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                        <Columns>
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCatID" HeaderText="Sub category ID">
                                                            <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                                            </asp:BoundField>
```

If I run, it looks like this. 2 more columns are not showing 
[image]

Could it be achieved by not using javascript? If I need to use "jquery-1.4.1.js" or "gridviewScroll.min.js" where can I download it? Sorry I'm pretty new to programming and I don't really know how to use javascript or jquery. 
It'd be great if I could add boarder lines in the gridview. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is case sensitive so `Overflow` wont work but `overflow` will. Try

```
<div style= "overflow:auto; max-height: 150px; width: 800px">
```

to only apply croll bars if needed or:

```
<div style= "overflow:scroll; max-height: 150px; width: 800px">
```

to always have scrollbars.

Finally, avoid using inline style, apply it as a class instead.

Comment: Thanks Jon! It solved my problem! I didn't know it's case sensitive :) But could I trouble you once more? It'd be easier to look if I could have grid lines displayed..... Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.gridlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx